# cask 'eclipse-java' is unreadable: undefined method 'before_colon'

Tags: eclipse, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I tried to update and upgrade Homebrew on MacBook Pro Intel 2018 MacOS Ventura 13.4.1 and failed to finish the upgrade with error message:

`Cask 'eclipse-java' is unreadable: undefined method 'before_colon' for "2021-09:R":Cask::DSL::Version Did you mean?  before_comma`

I've already tried brew doctor, uninstall the cask or reinstall the cask, and uninstalled eclipse and faced the same error message. And no, I won't reset my Homebrew because it would be a day work to install all the casks I have right now.

Has anyone encountered this kind of problem and would like to share the solution?
Thanks.

Comment: Several similar reports on the homebrew github site https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues?q=is%3Aissue+before_colon perhaps look at those. Note that Eclipse can be installed as a normal mac app and doesn't need to use homebrew.

Comment: yes, I had installed eclipse as an app from its website. I was surprised, too, when I faced this while I was updating and upgrading the brew.